# How to send error response with JSON body

Tags: d, vibed

I need to send JSON response with, for example, 403 HTTP error code. How can I achieve this in vibe.d?

I currently use this code:

```d
T enforceCode(T)(HTTPServerResponse res, T value, ErrorCodes code,
    HTTPStatus status = HTTPStatus.forbidden)
{
    if (!value) {
        res.writeJsonBody(["code": code], status);

        enforceHTTP(false, status);
    }
    return value;
}

void sendCode(T)(HTTPServerResponse res, ErrorCodes code, T errorInfo,
    HTTPStatus status = HTTPStatus.forbidden)
{
    import vibe.data.json;

    res.writeJsonBody([
        "code": Json(cast(int)code),
        "info": Json(serializeToJsonString(errorInfo))
    ], status);

    enforceHTTP(false, status); // I need to terminate current action
}
```

But other developers complain that error event triggered twice in the client application. With commented out `writeJsonBody` only once.

Comment: You should probably check for errors before you write anything to the stream, else the response may have already been sent.

Comment: Your call to writeJsonBody has already done what you want. Could you explain the necessity of the call to enforceHTTP, the comment suggests that you want to throw an exception to end processing of the request? It seems that this function is only called in error cases so I would assume logic in the consuming code should be written to prevent any further processing .

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, do you mean code that calls this functions? There's no errors in there.

Comment: @TractorPulledPork, Good suggestion. I updated question with another function I use. As you see it is preferred to use it in `assert`-like style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bug at client-side and not in above code.